# How make contents as a grid in a ScrollPanel in GWT project using UIBinder

Tags: java, css, gwt, scroll, uibinder

I've my GWT project where I have the following view of a list of movies: 
[image: here]

Blue boxes are CompositeWidgets inserted in a ScrollPanel.
I would like to obtain a grid (4 columns) and not a line as view. I'm a beginner in CSS, so I don't know how obtain my purpose. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your widgets with a FlowPanel, so that the structure will look like:

```
<g:ScrollPanel>
    <g:FlowPanel styleName="{style.canFitFourOnlyInaRow}">
       // add your blue boxes here
    </g:FlowPanel>
</g:ScrollPanel>
```

and define a style named `canFitFourOnlyInaRow` with width equal of 4 widths of your blue boxes + extra margins as needed.

```
<ui:style>
   .canFitFourOnlyInaRow {width: 500px;} /* 500px just for example */
</ui:style>
```

That will make blue box #5 to jump to the next line.

BTW, do you need vertical scroll only?

Comment: thanks for your advices, I have also added in css `float: left, margin: ... , padding: ....` to obtain a great result!